# When is a Gate potential zero?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, homework

I have this fairly simple NMOS and it is mentioned that I can determine the Source current \$I_3\$ with the formula \$ I_3 = \frac{K}{2}(V_{GS} - V_{th})^2 \$.

Here they equalize Gate Source Voltage \$ V_{GS}\$ with the Source potential \$ \varphi_S \$ and my question is why? Since the Gate Source Voltage is the potential difference between the Gate potential and the source potential \$ V_{GS} = \varphi_G - \varphi_S \$ this would mean that the Gate potential is zero. And since I don't see why this should be obvious or what am I missing, what circumstances would allow this assumption?

[image: NMOS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ V_{GS}\$ is what determines if the transistor is on or off. For an NMOS transistor \$ V_{GS}\$ is positive so the transistor turns on. If the transistor were fully off, \$\varphi_s\$ would be -5V and \$ V_{GS}\$ would be 5V which would cause the transistor to turn on.

Comment: And since the transistor doesn't have a powersource at the gate, it is turned off?

Comment: No, the gate voltage is higher than the source voltage, it would *turn on*. Current would then flow through the resistor and lower the gate voltage so some calculation is require to find out what the final vaules of this circuit are, I will leave that to you.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks!